# AWS CLI to get only Volumeid and tagvalue

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, aws-cli

From AWS using CLI to get volume details via describe-volumes

Sample volume Details

```
VolumeId = Vol-********
Attachments.InstanceId = i-*********
Tags : Key = Name     Value = sometext
```

Expected Output via AWS CLI:

```
Vol-********   i-*********   sometext
```

Codes I tried:

```
aws ec2 describe-volumes --query "Volumes[*].{ID:VolumeId,InstanceId:Attachments[0].InstanceId,Tag:Tags}" --output text
```

Output what I am getting:

```
Vol-********   i-*********
TAG    Name    sometext
```

Looking for help to get output as below.

Expected Output via AWS CLI:

```
Vol-********   i-*********   sometext
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a specific tag value of a volume:

```
aws ec2 describe-volumes --query "Volumes[*].{ID:VolumeId,InstanceId:Attachments[0].InstanceId,tag:Tags[0].Value}" --output text

vol-*******   i-******     second
```

If you are looking for all the tags value, it will come as below: `format= text`

```
aws ec2 describe-volumes --query "Volumes[*].{ID:VolumeId,InstanceId:Attachments[0].InstanceId,tag:Tags[].Value}" --output text

vol-0fa1417c2369e7440   i-0533e831213cf0cc4
TAG     second
TAG     test
```

If you are looking for all the tags value, it will come as below. `format= json`

```
aws ec2 describe-volumes --query "Volumes[*].{ID:VolumeId,InstanceId:Attachments[0].InstanceId,tag:Tags[].Value}" --output json

[
    {
        "InstanceId": "i-******",
        "tag": [
            "second",
            "test"
        ],
        "ID": "vol-******"
    }
]
```